# How to mock an imported subroutine when unit-testing a module

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, raku

Consider a module which exports a subroutine that connects to the Internet and returns a result:

```perl6
unit module A;

sub download is export {
     "result from internet"  # Not the actual implementation, obviously.
}
```

And another module which imports and calls that subroutine:

```perl6
use A;  # imports &download into this lexical scope
unit module B;

sub do-something is export {
     download().uc ~ "!!"   # Does something which involves calling &download
}
```

Now I'd like to write unit tests for module `B`.
But I don't want the tests to actually connect to the Internet; I'd like them to use a mock version of subroutine `download` that is controlled by my test script:

```perl6
use Test;
plan 2;

use B;

my $mock-result;
my &mock-download = -> { $mock-result }

# ...Here goes magic code that installs &mock-download
# as &download in B's lexical scope...

$mock-result = "fake result";
is do-something(), "FAKE RESULT!!", "do-something works - 1";

$mock-result = "foobar";
is do-something(), "FOOBAR!!", "do-something works - 2";
```

The problem is the missing magic code to override sub `download`...

In Perl 5, I think this could be achieved pretty easily using glob assignment, or even nicer with the help of [Sub::Override](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override) or [Test::MockModule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockModule).

But in Perl 6, the lexical scope of module `B` closes when it has finished compiling, and can thus no longer be modified by the time the test script is run (correct me if I'm wrong). So this approach doesn't seem possible.

How would one solve this task in Perl 6, then?
I.e. how would one write unit tests for `B::do-something`, without letting it call the real `A::download`?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach might be to use `wrap` which is described in https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#Routines but a prerequisite for that is the `use soft;` pragma which prevents inlining. You'd need to `use soft;` in module A:

```
unit module A;
use soft;

sub download is export {
    "result from internet";
}
```

Module B:

```
unit module B;
use A;

sub do-something is export {
    download.uc ~ "!!";
}
```

And the test script:

```
use Test;
use A;
use B;

&download.wrap({
    "mock result";
});

is do-something, "MOCK RESULT!!", "mock a 'use'd sub";
# ok 1 - mock a 'use'd sub
```

Comment: I am dissatisfied with this answer. It seems unreasonable to need a (usually external) module defined with `use soft;` in order to mock an imported sub. Is there really no way to modify A or B's symbol tables? If not, is there at least a way to modify module `B` in some way to make it more testable?

Comment: backtrack to new, related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042080/how-to-mock-a-class-method-when-unittesting-in-raku :: also, use soft is a pragma, not a module - so is universally available